# passport.js - authenticate users from MongoDB with passport-local

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I have a simple users collection in my MongoDB. I user mongo-native driver.

```
{
    "email": "johndow@example.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "50658c835b821298d3000001"
    }
}
```

As I user auth via pair email:pass, I re-wrote default passport-local function findByUsername to this:

```
function findByEmail(email, fn) {
    db.collection("users", function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({}, {}, function(err, users) {
            users.each(function(err, user) {
                if (user.email === email) {
                    return fn(null, user);
                }
            });
            return fn(null, null);
        });
    });
}
```

Just get all of the users form DB, and checking - if user.email == provided email, then return user object.

I use _id parameter of MongoDB as id for users, that's why I've modifies these two functions:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

And this is my code for passport local strategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy( function(email, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        console.log('initialize findByEmail() for "',email,'"');
        findByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                console.log('Unknown user ' + email)
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Unknown user ' + email

                });
            }
            if (user.password != password) {
                console.log('Invalid password')
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Invalid password'
                });
            }
            //сonsole.log('ALL VERIFIATION PASSED');
            return done(null, user);
        })
    });
}));
```

I post data from login page:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/desk');
});
```

And I get

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

and after this I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null
```

The last error is really strange 'cause findByEmail has console.log(user) line (removed from this listing) and it list all the user's data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not well documented, but `cursor.each` provides a `null` value to the second parameter of its callback to indicate that the cursor has no more documents available.  It's only mentioned in the example of the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each).

So in your case you should be checking for `user !== null` in your `users.each` callback.

However, it would be more efficient to have mongo do the searching for you by changing your `find` call to:

```
collection.findOne({email: email}, {}, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
        // email was found case
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, your trick helped me to remove the second error, but the first still remains...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Passport so I can't help you with that part.